# dc.js Show filtered count of objects

Tags: angular, dc.js

I'm new to dc.js. and i havent found a solution to my problem.

I have an array of objects like this

```
[{
 devicename: "device1",
 operatingSystem: "android",
 complainceState: "complaint"
 ...
},
{
 devicename: "device2",
 operatingSystem: "android",
 complainceState: "noncomplaint"
 ...
},
...]
```

Now i'm using a numberDisplay to try and show the amount of objects where complaincestate="complaint"
But it seems to show the amount of different values eg. 2 because there is "non complaint" and "complaint". What should i do to solve?

```
const complaincy = ndx.dimension((d: any) => d.complianceState)
      const complaincyGroup = complaincy.group()

      numberDisplay
      .formatNumber(d3.format(".1s"))
      .dimension(complaincy)
      .group(complaincyGroup)
```

this is the code i wrote. I've tried using .filter but it doesn't seem to work like i tought it would.

If anyone could point me to the right direction or link an article it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is some more context to my problem.

I currently have 2 charts and 1 number counter.[image]

This is the full code for dc.js

```
var deviceChart = dc.pieChart("#devices")
    var numberRowChart = dc.rowChart("#complaincy")
    var numberDisplay = dc.numberDisplay("#complaincyNumber")

this.tenantService.getDevicesD3(this.selectedTenant).then(data => {
      const ndx = crossfilter(data);

      //devices by os doughnut chart
      const deviceDimension = ndx.dimension((d:any) => d.operatingSystem);
      const deviceGroup = deviceDimension.group();

      deviceChart.ordinalColors(["#00a2ed","#3DDC84"]);
      deviceChart
      .radius(100)
      .width(160)
      .height(160)
      .dimension(deviceDimension)
      .group(deviceGroup)
      .innerRadius(50)
      .label((d) => "")
      .legend(dc.htmlLegend().container("#deviceLegend").highlightSelected(true))
      

      //non complaint number counter
      const complaincy = ndx.dimension((d: any) => d.complianceState)
      const complaincyGroup = complaincy.group()
      
      numberDisplay
      .formatNumber(d3.format(".1s"))
      .dimension(complaincy)

      //{
      //   value: () => complaincyGroup.all()
      //  .filter(({key}) => key == ‘complaint’)[0]
      //}
      // This solution suggested by gordon returns the following error in 
      //   console. ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
      .group(complaincyGroup);
      


      //number row chart
      numberRowChart
      .dimension(complaincy)
      .group(complaincyGroup)

      dc.renderAll();
      dc.redrawAll();

    })
```

Comment: not sure if your question is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is documented at the top of the [NumberDisplay documentation](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/NumberDisplay.html):

> If the group is a groupAll then its .value() will be displayed. This
> is the recommended usage.
>
> However, if it is given an ordinary group, the numberDisplay will show
> the last bin's value, after sorting with the ordering function.
> numberDisplay defaults the ordering function to sorting by value, so
> this will display the largest value if the values are numeric.

I guess you are seeing the last bin’s value.

Probably the easiest way to do what you want is to create a fake groupAll that returns only the element you want:

```
numberDisplay.group({
    value: () => complaincyGroup.all()
       .filter(({key}) => key == ‘complaint’)[0]})
```

Note: there is a misspelling in your code; if you spell your accessor like this

```
  const complaincy = ndx.dimension(d => d.complainceState)
```

then it works.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/hv3rojy8/10/).

Comment: Hi gordon, Thanks for the reply. I tried adding your code. But it doesnt show anything and returns this error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". I've also added some more context to my question as it may not have been clear enough.

Comment: Unfortunately if you have a simple typo you'll often get empty groups and such. It's best to print your `group.all()` to the console to see if you're getting what you expect. You had a typo in your `complaincy` definition, which I've described above, and I linked an example fiddle.